# Very slow sql query for count

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, yii

I need get report count for each user role, but my sql query very slow (40 sec on good server). My sql query:

```
SELECT `auth_assignment`.`item_name`, COUNT(*) as count
FROM `report`
LEFT JOIN `company` ON company.id = report.company_id
LEFT JOIN `auth_assignment` 
ON auth_assignment.user_id = company.user_id
GROUP BY `auth_assignment`.`item_name`
ORDER BY `count`
```

`auth_assignment`.`item_name` is role type.

`auth_assignment` has ~23k rows.
`company` ~11k rows.

`reports` ~12k rows (one company can have many reports).

`report`.`id` and `company`.`id`, have binding

Comment: Have you examined query execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are aggregating on a column from the *third* table in a `left join`.  I'm guessing you don't want `NULL` for the value, so use `inner join` or change the order of the tables.

Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT aa.item_name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM report r JOIN
     company c
     ON c.id = r.company_id JOIN
     auth_assignment aa
     ON aa.user_id = c.user_id
GROUP BY aa.item_name
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Assuming the join's are correct for the tables, then you just want to be sure that you have indexes.  These should go on the columns used for the `join`s:  `company(id, user_id)`, `auth_assignment(user_id, item_name)`.

Comment: Thanks, with inner join my query time is 0.06 sec

Comment: 99.8% improvement.  Nice.